# Get-ADComputer -Filter

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a script that uploads data about a PC with the last activity more than 100 days, I can’t upload it as a normal table and I don’t understand how to add 2 distributionname + description fields

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties OperatingSystem, LastLogonDate |      Where { $_.LastLogonDate -LT (Get-Date).AddDays(-100) } |     Select-Object Name, OperatingSystem, LastLogonDate  | Out-File "\\Client\C$\Users\computer_ad.csv"   -encoding Unicode -Delimiter ";"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `Out-File` to save as CSV. There is a special cmdlet for that called [Export-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv)

Also, it is better to set the reference date to midnight using `.Date` when comparing to the LastLogonDate.

By default, Get-ADComputer returns these properties:
`DistinguishedName, DNSHostName, Enabled, Name, ObjectClass, ObjectGUID, SamAccountName, SID,  UserPrincipalName` and for anything on top of that you need to specify it in the `-Properties` parameter.

As for attribute `Description`, that's easy enough, but what do you mean by `distributionname` ??
I'm guessing you want the `DistinguishedName` name there:

```
$refDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-100).Date  # set this to midnight
Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties OperatingSystem, LastLogonDate, Description | 
Where-Object { $_.LastLogonDate -lt $refDate } | 
Select-Object Name, OperatingSystem, LastLogonDate, Description, DistinguishedName | 
Export-Csv -Path "\\Client\C$\Users\computer_ad.csv" -Delimiter ';' -NoTypeInformation
```

If you really want the file to be encoded in UTF16-LE (Unicode), you can add that to the Export-Csv line: `-Encoding Unicode`, although `UTF8` is more commonly used.